# Looping through json object nested properties and displaying them if not null - vue

Tags: javascript, json, object

need to go through a JSON object which might or might not have 'properties' fields it can be null or it can have 10 different ones which you would not know what they actually are called, I then need to print it in a code block, the JSON data is here:

```json
{
  "alias": "AS",
  "id": "4a4e1584-b0a7-4069-8851-0ee7f9e18267",
  "name": "asdfadf",
  "properties": {
    "shape": null,
    "units": "gms",
    "dimension": null,
    "maxWeight": "sdf",
    "minWeight": "asfd"
  },
}
```

The output needs to be a string such as Units: gms, MaxWeight: sdf... Or these can be 'size' or anything else someone specifies in the extra properties but they will be under the properties.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you question correctly you need to see the `properties` inside the object if `properties` is not null.

You just need to check if it's not null and loop through it.

```js
let j = {
            "alias": "AS",
            "id": "4a4e1584-b0a7-4069-8851-0ee7f9e18267",
            "name": "asdfadf",
            "properties": {
                "shape": null,
                "units": "gms",
                "dimension": null,
                "maxWeight": "sdf",
                "minWeight": "asfd"
            },
}

if(j.properties !== null){
    for(let key in j.properties){
        console.log(` ${key} : ${j.properties[key]}`)
    }
}
```

If you need help with something in Vue you can include that in your question too, so we can see exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: thanks that somehow worked on only the first properties not sure why I know it works here, I got the answer anyway I think thanks though!!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this, basically you can iterate over the `properties`' properties using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), access the values and then combine them into a string as follows:

```js
const data = {
  "alias": "AS",
  "id": "4a4e1584-b0a7-4069-8851-0ee7f9e18267",
  "name": "asdfadf",
  "properties": {
    "shape": null,
    "units": "gms",
    "dimension": null,
    "maxWeight": "sdf",
    "minWeight": "asfd"
  },
};

function propertiesToString(data) {
  return Object.keys(data).map((key) => key + ':' + data[key]).join(', ')
}

console.log(propertiesToString(data.properties));
```

Comment: That did not work I'm not sure why, specifically in my example, it works here, I have the answer anyway I think but thanks for the contribution!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and some Array prototype methods to filter out `null`s and properly stringify the result.

```js
var obj = JSON.parse('{"alias":"AS","id":"4a4e1584-b0a7-4069-8851-0ee7f9e18267","name":"asdfadf","properties":{"shape":null,"units":"gms","dimension":null,"maxWeight":"sdf","minWeight":"asfd"}}');

function getPropertyString(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj)
  .filter(el => el[1] != null)
  .map(el => el.join(': '))
  .join(', ');
}
  
console.log(getPropertyString(obj.properties));
```

Step by step:

1. *`Object.entries(obj)`* – Returns an array of arrays, structured as:
   `[[key1, value1], [key2, value2], ... , [keyN, valueN]]`
2. *`Array.prototype.filter(func)`* – Returns a copy of the array with all elements that return `true` from the provided callback

   - In this case, filters out all arrays from `entries` that have a `null` value
3. *`Array.prototype.map(func)`* – Returns a copy of the array after transforming each element with the provided callback

   - In this case, transforms all `[key, value]` arrays to be a string with the format `"key: value"`
4. *`Array.prototype.join(str)`* – Returns a string representing the array with each element joined by the provided string

   - Joins the `"key: value"` strings to each other with `", "` in between